# Diff shows tag being added and removed in the same revision

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, tags, revisions-list, diff

On [this question's revisions](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/posts/40688/revisions) (but I remember seeing it in other cases) the diff shows the same tag being both added and removed.

[image: A tag is both added and removed]

Answer (score 18):

The tagging system automatically sorts tags based on how many times they're used. However, this is relatively new, so when a new edit is processed for an old post, the system sees the sort as a delete and re-insert because it is now in a new position.

Such edits [*do* count for the Organizer badge](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/71037/377214), even though the actual tags are the same in the end.

Also of note: rollbacks do not consider tag order, and a rollback to a revision where the tags are in a different order will leave them in whatever order they were in when that revision was made. Another edit will then reorder them *again*.

Comment: Not only that, but sometimes I've removed accidentally a tag from the beginning , and added it last. It shows in that way too.