# Undeserved Organizer badge

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, badges, edits

A few days ago I undeservedly received the [Organizer badge](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/badges/5/organizer) even though I didn't touch any tag. The tags were automatically reordered (see below). [Revision list](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/posts/283/revisions).

Is this a bug?

---

[alt text http://drmortensen.eu/SE20/Undeserved_Organiser_badge,2010-07-14_16c.png](http://drmortensen.eu/SE20/Undeserved_Organiser_badge,2010-07-14_16c.png)

Comment: Either you have a very steady hand or *you used the line tool on those arrows instead of drawing them freehand!* :o

Comment: +1 for the yellow freehand circle, that's beautiful.

Comment: @Andy, I've drawn freehand lines that I've had to go erase and redo because they looked too perfect.  I use a touchpad, which drops the level of difficulty down quite a bit.  (Of course, if he claims that he drew "Tag order changed" freehand, I'll be a bit suspicious....)

Comment: @Pop: lol yeah I've done that - I work mostly from my laptop and it's much easier to draw straight freehand lines.  Still hard to draw circles though!

Comment: @Andy, I initially wrote "freehand lines/circles" and then realized that my circles were still fairly bad (though not as bad as they would be with a mouse).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Can you swear by God, that you didn't put your cursor (maybe accidentally) into the tags' text field and refocusing afterwards? Then you have triggered the automatic reorder. Which means, you have re-organised the tags.

You can't swear? Well, then:

## In the name of people: Guilty!

Comment: I have most certainly stepped through the tag field with the tab key in order to get to the Save button. I must be guilty. Thanks for clearing it up. Has the principle of least surprise been violated in this case?

Comment: @Peter: Jeff took you by surprise here, so ... no! :]

Comment: this auto-reorder-by-popularity happens on the server, so whether you tabbed through the field or not is irrelevant

Answer (score 5):

This is basically by design, as tags are now automatically reordered from left to right in order of popularity. So if you edit a post, and the tags happen to be in the wrong popularity order, that will trigger a retag on your behalf.

The good news is that it should be relatively rare.