# Tags added while removed?

Tags: bug, tags, revisions-list, diff

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Diff shows tag being added and removed in the same revision](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/56216/diff-shows-tag-being-added-and-removed-in-the-same-revision)

[xcode](/questions/tagged/xcode) is both added and removed at the same time here:

https://stackoverflow.com/posts/377992/revisions

[image: Image of the xcode tag being added and removed]

Is this by design or a bug?

Comment: One can't tell, but [this is a duplicate of this question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/56216/diff-shows-tag-being-added-and-removed-in-the-same-revision). With your permission, I'd like to steal your image here and repaste it on that question. To save your navigation time, by the way, the answer (by design) is that edit actions will "rearrange" tags if their popularity shifts. So xcode went from being the least used, to the most used, in that question.

Comment: Hereby I release the screenshot into public domain. Of course you have my permission.

Comment: @Grace Note, just a nitpick: the question linked here was actually asked long before tags started being auto-sorted by popularity.

Comment: @mmyers The question was asked long before, but the *revision* is post-feature. And that's what triggers it, is that there was a revision. You needn't even modify the tags to trigger it. The tag order doesn't update between revisions, as far as I know.

Comment: @Grace Note: Yes, I know. It was a very minor nitpick: you said that the popularity had shifted when that may not be the case.

Comment: @mmyers Oh, that's what you meant. Haha, I see. That's actually a very valid point, thank you much. ♪ There are a lot of old questions that are sitting with entirely unordered tags, actually.