# Tag edit shows tag both removed and added

Tags: discussion, tags, edits

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Diff shows tag being added and removed in the same revision](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/56216/diff-shows-tag-being-added-and-removed-in-the-same-revision)
>   [Tags added while removed?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/80245/tags-added-while-removed)

Is this behavior intentional, or at least accepted?

[image: tag edit]

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is intentional. Tags are automatically sorted whenever the question is edited to reflect the popularity of each tag. If another tag eventually becomes more or less popular, it needs to be shifted to its new, proper position. In this case, the Python tag was removed and re-added because it was misplaced based on tag popularity. This also occurs on very old questions, which did not sort tags at all when questions were initially posted (they were stored in the order they were entered).

Comment: Thanks.  Is this described anywhere or is it knowledge gained by observation?

Comment: It's something I've learned over time, but Grace Note says about the same thing in the comments of the question I linked as a duplicate.